# Add a track to iTunes programmatically from Sandboxed Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have an mp3 file that I want to be added to iTunes and it is in a sandboxed Mac App

I am trying to start iTunes and add to its library

I thought of

```
NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itunes://localpath"];
```

or

```
NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
[ws LaunchApplication @"iTunes" ]
some how listen to launch events and pass local path NSURL
```

Would any of that work on a sandboxed app?

Comment: Ask not what a sandboxed application can do for you.  Ask what AppleScript can do for your sandboxed application.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/info03.php) site out it list's loads of apple script commands to implement songs, playlists, e.t.c into iTunes. 
However I believe you would need code like this:

**Commands from the iTunes Suite**

**add**
Add a new track or tracks to the iTunes library. Audio CD tracks will be imported to your computer.
The add command requires the alias of the file(s) in a list (lists are enclosed by brackets and the values in a list are separated by commas). You can also designate an extant playlist to copy the track to:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    -- 'choose file' returns an alias
    set newFile to (choose file with prompt "Select a song to add...")
    add newFile to playlist "Check These Out!"
end tell
```

The add command returns a reference to the track added, so:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set newFile to (choose file with prompt "Select a song to add...")
    set new_track to (add newFile to playlist "Check These Out!")
    set comment of new_track to "Some comment for this example"
end tell
```

I'm sorry this does not match your question. However the best way to perform the task you are talking about will require Apple Script.

Happy coding :)